# cmake linking against static libraries - do you have to tell cmake where to look?

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, pcapplusplus

I've installed the c++ library `pcapplusplus` on my linux machine and the `.a` files have been put in `/usr/local/lib`. I am now trying to link my project with it in cmake using `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libCommon++.a libPacket++.a libPcap++.a)`. However, it can't find `Packet.h` which is part of `libPacket++.a`. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to tell cmake where to look?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(networksniffer)
# The version number.
set (networksniffer_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (networksniffer_VERSION_MINOR 0)

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

# The following folder will be included
include_directories("/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus")

#add_executable(networksniffer ${SOURCES})
add_executable(networksniffer ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/networksniffer.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libCommon++.a libPacket++.a libPcap++.a)
```

Answer (score 6):

`Packet.h` is not part of `libPacket++.a`.

`libPacket++.a` is a library, `Packet.h` is a header file.

CMake can't know that both relate to each other unless you tell it so.

I suggest using `find_package` to properly locate both (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html).

Use `target_include_directories` then to include the path to the header file.

Comment: thanks I've updated my cmakelists.txt file in my original post. Adding `include_directories("/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus")` resolved the issue of find `Packet.h`. However, now the project builds and I am getting `undefined reference to `pcpp::compute_checksum()` which I read is a linking error.

Comment: And of course these days you would prefer to use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_include_directories.html) over the plain old `include_directories`.

Comment: @netleaptom this is a different issue. Please post a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add header search directory path where compiler can find header file in your case `Packet.h`

You can try command `locate Packet.h` to find out path on your system. Then you can add that path with `include_directories()` function. i.e. if you found `Packet.h` in `/usr/local/include/` then you should update like below.

```
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"/include "/usr/local/include/")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because it is not able to find the header file. I see that you havent mentioned any include folders. The file Packet.h must be in /usr/local/include. You can either include this. 
OR you can add something like this

```
find_package(pcapplusplus REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCAPPLUSPLUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Take care of varible names yourself.

Comment: I tried it, however I believe .cmake is missing. The following error was shown: `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcapplusplus" with
any of the following names: pcapplusplusConfig.cmake pcapplusplus-config.cmake`