# Inclusion pcapplusplus in project via CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, pcapplusplus

I installed pcapplusplus on Ubuntu (Downloaded package from here: https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/tag/v21.11). The example that was in the archive compiles and works, everything is fine with it! But when I try to include the library in my project using CMake nothing works.

I write a line in CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include_directories("/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus")
```

After that, the header files are connected to the project. However, the project does not compile, various errors appear depending on the functions that I use. Most likely the linker does not see the files: libCommon++.a, libPacket++.a, and libPcap++.a.
I tried to connect them like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libCommon++.a libPacket++.a libPcap++.a)
```

But it did not help.
Tried this:

```
find_package(pcapplusplus REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCAPPLUSPLUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

This didn't help either.

In fact, other people have already encountered such a problem, for example, netleap tom wrote about this on the StackOverflow. [cmake linking against static libraries - do you have to tell cmake where to look?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165990/cmake-linking-against-static-libraries-do-you-have-to-tell-cmake-where-to-look)
However, no one there suggested a solution to him. I hope someone will tell me what to do.

udp.

Hello World from [here](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/v1808/tutorial_intro.html) for example:

```
#include <IPv4Layer.h>
#include <Packet.h>
#include <PcapFileDevice.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice reader("1_packet.pcap");
    if (!reader.open())
    {
        printf("Error opening the pcap file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pcpp::RawPacket rawPacket;
    if (!reader.getNextPacket(rawPacket))
    {
        printf("Couldn't read the first packet in the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (parsedPacket.isPacketOfType(pcpp::IPv4))
    {
        pcpp::IPv4Address srcIP = parsedPacket.getLayerOfType<pcpp::IPv4Layer>()->getSrcIpAddress();
        pcpp::IPv4Address destIP = parsedPacket.getLayerOfType<pcpp::IPv4Layer>()->getDstIpAddress();
        printf("Source IP is '%s'; Dest IP is '%s'\n", srcIP.toString().c_str(), destIP.toString().c_str());
    }
    reader.close();
    return 0;
}
```

If I add only this to CMake:

```
include_directories("/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus")
```

I have the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcpp::Packet::~Packet()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4pcpp6PacketD2Ev[_ZN4pcpp6PacketD5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `pcpp::Packet::destructPacketData()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcpp::Packet::~Packet()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN4pcpp6PacketD0Ev[_ZN4pcpp6PacketD5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `pcpp::Packet::destructPacketData()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `pcpp::IPv4Layer* pcpp::Packet::getLayerOfType<pcpp::IPv4Layer>(bool) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b[_ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b]+0x1b): undefined reference to `typeinfo for pcpp::IPv4Layer'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b[_ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b]+0x22): undefined reference to `typeinfo for pcpp::Layer'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b[_ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b]+0x4e): undefined reference to `typeinfo for pcpp::IPv4Layer'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b[_ZNK4pcpp6Packet14getLayerOfTypeINS_9IPv4LayerEEEPT_b]+0x55): undefined reference to `typeinfo for pcpp::Layer'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main.cold':
main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x58): undefined reference to `pcpp::Packet::destructPacketData()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x63): undefined reference to `pcpp::RawPacket::~RawPacket()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x8a): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::~IFileDevice()'
```

More here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfOiB.png).

If I add this to CMake:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libCommon++.a libPacket++.a libPcap++.a)
```

I have the following errors (first five):

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPacket++.a(EthLayer.o): in function `pcpp::EthLayer::toString[abi:cxx11]() const':
/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/EthLayer.cpp:104: undefined reference to `pcpp::MacAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/EthLayer.cpp:104: undefined reference to `pcpp::MacAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPacket++.a(EthDot3Layer.o): in function `pcpp::EthDot3Layer::toString[abi:cxx11]() const':
/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/EthDot3Layer.cpp:36: undefined reference to `pcpp::MacAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/EthDot3Layer.cpp:36: undefined reference to `pcpp::MacAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPacket++.a(DhcpLayer.o): in function `pcpp::DhcpLayer::getClientHardwareAddress() const':
/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/DhcpLayer.cpp:83: undefined reference to `pcpp::MacAddress::Zero'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPacket++.a(PayloadLayer.o): in function `pcpp::PayloadLayer::PayloadLayer(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Packet++/src/PayloadLayer.cpp:24: undefined reference to `pcpp::hexStringToByteArray(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*, unsigned long)'
```

More here: [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBWiv.png)

```
 undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileReaderDevice::IFileReaderDevice(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x63): undefined reference to `vtable for pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb5): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::~IFileDevice()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTIN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for pcpp::IFileDevice'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcpp::IFileDevice::close()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcpp::IPcapDevice::setFilter(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcpp::IPcapDevice::clearFilter()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x78): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to pcpp::IPcapDevice::setFilter(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE[_ZTVN4pcpp17IFileReaderDeviceE]+0x80): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to pcpp::IPcapDevice::clearFilter()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: "Most likely the linker does not see the files ..." - The error about not finding specified libraries would clearly say that. If you in doubt about the meaning the error message you got, then it means something else. Please, add to the question post the **exact error message** you got when use the code you show us.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, lets take Hello World from [here](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/v1808/tutorial_intro.html) as an example. I have updated my post.

Comment: It is requirement of Stack Overflow to have code and error message in the question post itself as **text**, not linked as *images*. Even if your code is taken from tutorial, copy paste your code here. Then read about where to find in your IDE **textual** representation of errors, and paste these errors into the question post too. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated my post. Thanks for u recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Pcap++ Packet++ Common++ pcap pthread)
```

this is the order as listed in the pcapplusplus example mk file /usr/local/etc/PcapPlusPlus.mk

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://github.com/gleb-kun/pcappp_hw

As expected, errors occurred due to incorrect library connection using CMake.

A file FindPcapPlusPlus.cmake is required to connect. Add the following lines to the main file CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PcapPlusPlus_LIBRARIES})
```

FindPcapPlusPlus.cmake file contents:

```
if (PC_PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDEDIR AND PC_PcapPlusPlus_LIBDIR)
    set(PcapPlusPlus_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
endif ()

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(PC_PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED PcapPlusPlus)

set(PcapPlusPlus_VERSION ${PC_PcapPlusPlus_VERSION})

mark_as_advanced(PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDE_DIR PcapPlusPlus_LIBRARY)

foreach (LIB_NAME ${PC_PcapPlusPlus_LIBRARIES})
    find_library(${LIB_NAME}_PATH ${LIB_NAME} HINTS ${PC_PcapPlusPlus_LIBDIR})
    if (${LIB_NAME}_PATH)
        list(APPEND PcapPlusPlus_LIBS ${${LIB_NAME}_PATH})
    endif ()
endforeach ()

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(PcapPlusPlus
        REQUIRED_VARS PC_PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDEDIR PC_PcapPlusPlus_LIBDIR
        VERSION_VAR PcapPlusPlus_VERSION
        )

if (PcapPlusPlus_FOUND)
    set(PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PC_PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDEDIR})
    set(PcapPlusPlus_LIBRARIES ${PcapPlusPlus_LIBS})
endif ()

if (PcapPlusPlus_FOUND AND NOT TARGET PcapPlusPlus::PcapPlusPlus)
    add_library(PcapPlusPlus::PcapPlusPlus INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(PcapPlusPlus::PcapPlusPlus PROPERTIES
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${PcapPlusPlus_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
            INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${PcapPlusPlus_LIBRARIES}"
            INTERFACE_COMPILE_FLAGS "${PC_PcapPlusPlus_CFLAGS}"
            )
endif ()
```